Download manager Enable - Android 7.1.2
I'm having problems installing scalefusion on Android 7.1.2 when I give permission this message appears:

kindly enable download manager

I've looked for many apps and there's no way to do it
I looked for a download manager on my Android but it doesn't exist, I installed a backdoor to install via the command line using adb activate:
adb shell pm enable com.android.providers.downloads

